# jquery: animate down navigation, not sliding back up/working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, navigationbar

Hey so i was trying to get my navigation to animate down after a certain div has passed but its not working properly. not sure why. it works when sliding down although a bit buggy(sometimes there seems to be a delay before it slides down and other times it slides down properly immediately). It also does not slide up it justs removes it self.
what am i doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    targetScroll = $('#scroll_verder').position().top,
    currentScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
if(currentScroll>=targetScroll){
    $('.navbar').addClass('show-menu').animate({ top: '0px' });
}

else {
    $('.navbar').stop();
    $('.navbar').removeClass('show-menu');
    $('.navbar').animate({ top: '-50px' });
}
});
```

Comment: Is this code hosted somewhere one could take a look at it? The delay probably comes from the animation function duration when the navbar is traveling over a short distance (400ms is default... so I'm guessing there will be a delay if you ex. move it a couple of pixels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a look at your code on the link you posted. This should do the trick:

```
var reachedTarget = false; // Prevent animation collisions with this
var targetScroll = $('#scroll_verder').position().top;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var currentScroll = $('html').scrollTop() || $('body').scrollTop();
  if ( currentScroll >= targetScroll ) {
    if ( !reachedTarget ) {
      $('.navbar').stop();
      $('.navbar').addClass('show-menu').animate({ top: '0px' });
    }
    reachedTarget = true;
  } else{
    if ( reachedTarget ) {
      $('.navbar').stop();
      $('.navbar').removeClass('show-menu').animate({ top: '-50px' });
    }
    reachedTarget = false;
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** In CSS (to make sure initial position is correct):

```
.navbar.show-menu {
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  top : -50px;
}
```

Comment: @johnzy87db How about a vote if this answer worker out for you ? ;)